# css background positioning not working

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at [this](http://carwrapping.traxx.li/warum-folie.html). If the background positioning (left wrapper `right top`, right wrapper `left top`) worked, the gas pumps would fit neatly besides the content box. But they don't and I cant seem to find out why...

HTML

```
<body>
    <!-- navigation stuff -->
    <div class="w3-row">
        <div id="fill-left" class="w3-col s1 m2 l3">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="main" class="w3-col s10 m8 l6">
            <div id="content" class="w3-container w3-white">
                <p>Lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fill-right" class="w3-col s1 m2 l3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#fill-left {
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(bgleft.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right top;
}

#fill-right {
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(bgright.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left top;
}

div#main {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #000;
}
```

Note: the w3-xxx classes stem from a CSS library called W3.CSS; used by me for simple responsive site layouting. Don't hate me...

**tj;dr**
What I precisely need is to put the fixed point of the bg-image to the top directly next to the content - making the background stretch out from the conent area.

Comment: Change the background position to numbers instead. ex: `background-position: -100px 720px;` and play with the numbers till you find the result you want

Comment: That wouldn't be responsive or am I mistaken?

Comment: @OmriLuzon what I meant was "kinda-responsive" positioning. I want the gas things (dammit, what are these things called?!) to show besides the content. On smaller screens there will be no backgroudn image at all and on larger screens it will show more image besides the gas things to the outer corners. I just need this positioning to work in a dynamic manner.

Comment: @traxx2012 gas pumps?

Comment: @traxx2012 you have 47 rep and 2 posted answers to your question. Upvotes cost nothing and acknowledge people's time and effort put into helping you. Accept working answers. I note you don't do this very often! It's easy, hover beside an answer and click the checkbox!!... Consider using your votes and accepting answers! You gain rep when you accept answers!

Comment: @traxx2012 yay, i just noticed you upvoted both answers [and accepted mine!] .. thanks :) I upvoted your question in return.. especially cos you were so close to the 50 milestone.. "favours for favours" - quote Radiohead :) (Fitter Happier on OK Computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at this, and solved it by re-jigging the html (still used your w3.css but added classes for the backgrounds). I removed the `background-attachment:fixed;` and added a `no-repeat` and `background-size` to the background.

Hope this helps

```css
#fill-left,
#content,
#fill-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0!important;
  position: relative;
}

.bg1 {
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: -3;
  background-image: url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg");
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  //float:left;
}

.bg2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: -3;
  background-image: url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: right!important;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #000;
}

#content {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  background-position: center top;
  z-index: 0;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
  color: #8B0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="main" class="w3-row">
  <div id="fill-left" class="bg1 w3-col s1 m2 l3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="content" class="w3-container w3-white">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fill-right" class="bg2 w3-col s1 m2 l3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: widths should be adjusted as you see fit but you get the gist..  fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zL0ptfts/

Answer (score 1):

To get the content to show up in a more proper manner, I switched up the images and the positioning.  I also added a background-size:contain;  to both elements. As for responsiveness, I would setup a media query to allow these images to disappear when that menu does as well. I also noticed that the menu items are wrapping quite a bit before the menu disappears.  Just a heads up in case you haven't noticed that yet.

```
#fill-left {
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(bgright.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left;
}

#fill-right {
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(bgleft.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: i have noticed, but thanks. Swapping the images doesn't really solve the problem because the background image is an airbrush artwork on the workshops wall - so it wouldn't be as recognizable...